# How to cross join 3 columns together?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have 2 tables, first one is material_table:

| id | material |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | steel |
| 2 | aluminum |
| 3 | copper |
| 4 | nickel |

Second one is dimension_table:

| width | length |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |

I want to join them so I have something like result_table:

| material | width | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| steel | 1 | 1 |
| steel | 1 | 2 |
| steel | 1 | 3 |

I tried the following:

```
SELECT material_table.type, dimension_table.width, dimension_table.length
FROM dimensions_table
CROSS JOIN material_table;
```

But I get a resulting table like:

| material | width | length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| steel | 1 | 1 |
| copper | 1 | 1 |
| nickel | 1 | 1 |
| steel | 1 | 2 |
| copper | 1 | 2 |
| nickel | 1 | 2 |

So to clarify I want to join my material table with the dimensions table, but the order of the columns is not the way I want it.

Comment: add an `order by` clause then

Comment: Could you elaborate? Trying to sort by '''ORDER BY mat_type DESC''' has completely out of order results for the dimensions column. ie. the dimensions columns are completely out of order, starting at 19 and going back to 9 and jumping forward again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to order every field that should be ordered. To be guaranteed to have the same output as expected, it would be:

```sql
SELECT material_table.type, dimension_table.width, dimension_table.length
FROM dimensions_table
CROSS JOIN material_table
ORDER BY material_table.type, dimension_table.width, dimension_table.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT material_table.type, dimension_table.width, dimension_table.length
FROM dimensions_table
CROSS JOIN material_table
ORDER BY material_table.type
```